# How efficient is it to reuse the command and connection object in ADO.net?

Tags: odp.net, oraclecommand

There is a specific requirement where in I am required to connect to two different Oracle databases one after the other. Does it make sense to create new connection and command objects or should I reuse them like below? (Not sure if this would even work-just some pseudo code here)

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString1);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("StoredProcedure1 , conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.parameters.add("param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2 , 20 , ParameterDirection.Input);
conn.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.close();

// Second DB hit
conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString2;
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedure1";
if (cmd.Parameters.Count > 0)  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.parameters.add("param2", OracleDbType.Varchar2 , 30 , ParameterDirection.Input);
conn.open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.close();
```

All criticism welcome.

Comment: What are the actual requirements that would lead you to to consider this approach? Just how time-critical is this? If I absolutely had to go about it this way, I would feel more comfortable creating two connection objects and two command objects and then performing `Open` / `ExecuteNonQuery` / `Close` (or `Dispose`) on them.

Comment: I had wanted to complete the whole operation with the same object. I did not see a need to create a new one..either way we have actually changed the while business and the approach.. This is no longer required.. Though I am curious to know if it would make any difference than using two separate objects or if connection pooling would already take care of it in case we do decide to use multiple connections..